# Cypress - cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route

Tags: cypress

Fairly new to Cypress and it's been smooth sailing so far until I wanted to fake out a network request. Code is like this:

```
describe('Some test', function(){
it('Can fake out an XHR response', function(){
    cy.server()
    cy.route('https://reqres.in/api/users', [{ id: 1, name: 'Pat' }]).as('getMessages')
    cy.request('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    cy.wait(['@getMessages'])
```

...

No matter what I try I get:

CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'getMessages'. No request ever occurred.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I changed the code to this:

```
cy.server()
cy.route('https://reqres.in/api/users', [{ id: 1, name: 'Pat' }]).as('getMessages')
cy.request('https://reqres.in/api/users')
cy.wait(['@getMessages'])
```

But the result was as below:

[image]

Comment: Cypress has known issues with XHR. Try some of the suggested workarounds in the comments section of their issues page  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/95

Comment: There is also a massive issue thread about wait()'s not resolving here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3427

Comment: Could be fixed now by [Cypress@4.9.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#4-9-0)?

Comment: See this answer in other similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75479520/8743267

Answer (score 1):

As of Cypress 6.0.0 *cy.intercept()* is the successor to *cy.route()* and can be used to return an expected response as follows:

```
cy.intercept('GET','/api/users', expectedResult).as('interceptedRequest');

cy.wait('@interceptedRequest');
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept