# CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms

Tags: cypress

I am making a call to an api, 'GET'. Once the test is started for the first time, the error appears: CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms.Running the test again without closing it works.

Is there any solution for this?
What can you try to do?
Is it Cypress's problem?

[image: Code]

[image: First Time]

[image]

Comment: did you try increasing timeout ?

Comment: Yes, but not found, the same error

Comment: You should put the cy.intercept before the action that causes the request to happen, then do the action, then put the cy.wait

Comment: Explain yourself better, because my code is structured as you mention

Answer (score 0):

Test by disabling the browser cache. This error happens when the browser caches the call, then the test fails because technically the call is never being made (since the browser pulls the response from the cache):
[Image of disabling cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3X39.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).